# Dividing Pandas Dataframe by Week

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, resampling

I have a dataframe with columns "Date" and "Num".

```
dates = pd.date_range('1/1/2001','1/1/2003', freq = 'd')
nums = [np.random.randint(100) for x in range(len(dates))]

df = pd.DataFrame({'Dates': dates, 'DOW': dates.strftime('%a'), 'Nums': nums})
df = df[(df.DOW != 'Sat') & (df.DOW !='Sun')]
df = df.drop([7,18]).reset_index(drop = True)
```

I need to bin the dataframe so I can isolate each week separately. The ultimate goal is to look at the MAX 'Nums' value for each week and compare it to the LAST value of the following week to see what the percent change is. For example:

```
week1 = df[0:5]
week2 = df[5:9]
week3 = df[9:12]

In [156]: w1max = week1.Nums.max()
Out[156]: 97

In [157]: w2Last = week2.iloc[-1].Nums
Out[157]: 76

pctChange = (w2Last-w1max)/float(w1max)

In [166]: pctChange
Out[166]: -0.21649484536082475
```

The problem is that some weeks are missing days (eg week2 is missing monday and week3 is missing friday). So how do I separate them out?

The closest thing seems to be using `df.resample()` but I don't know how to make the comparison I'm trying to make using that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
np.random.seed(2016)

dates = pd.date_range('1/1/2001','1/1/2003', freq = 'd')
nums = [np.random.randint(100) for x in range(len(dates))]

df = pd.DataFrame({'Dates': dates, 'DOW': dates.strftime('%a'), 'Nums': nums})
df = df[(df.DOW != 'Sat') & (df.DOW !='Sun')]
df = df.drop([7,18]).reset_index(drop = True)

df2 = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='W', key='Dates'))['Nums'].agg(['max','last'])
df2['previous_max'] = df2['max'].shift(1)
df2['change'] = (df2['last']-df2['previous_max'])/df2['previous_max']
print(df2.head())
```

yields

```
            max  last  previous_max    change
Dates                                        
2001-01-07   83    39           NaN       NaN
2001-01-14   75    75          83.0 -0.096386
2001-01-21   97    18          75.0 -0.760000
2001-01-28   72    37          97.0 -0.618557
2001-02-04   84    24          72.0 -0.666667
```

---

`df.groupby` with a [`pd.Grouper` object](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Grouper.html) can be used to group the rows by weeks.
You can use the `agg` method to find both the `max` and the `last` value for the `Nums` in each group:

```
In [163]: df2 = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='W', key='Dates'))['Nums'].agg(['max','last'])

In [164]: df2.head()
Out[164]: 
            max  last
Dates                
2001-01-07   83    39
2001-01-14   75    75
2001-01-21   97    18
2001-01-28   72    37
2001-02-04   84    24
```

Then use `shift(1)` to shift the `max` values down by one row:

```
In [165]: df2['previous_max'] = df2['max'].shift(1); df2.head()
Out[165]: 
            max  last  previous_max
Dates                              
2001-01-07   83    39           NaN
2001-01-14   75    75          83.0
2001-01-21   97    18          75.0
2001-01-28   72    37          97.0
2001-02-04   84    24          72.0
```

Then the percent change can be computed by simple subtraction and division:

```
In [166]: df2['change'] = (df2['last']-df2['previous_max'])/df2['previous_max']; df2.head()
Out[166]: 
            max  last  previous_max    change
Dates                                        
2001-01-07   83    39           NaN       NaN
2001-01-14   75    75          83.0 -0.096386
2001-01-21   97    18          75.0 -0.760000
2001-01-28   72    37          97.0 -0.618557
2001-02-04   84    24          72.0 -0.666667
```

Comment: brilliant, did not know about .shift and .Grouper